# i am unable to lock some part of the screen while using "Scroll View"

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

i am implementing one data enter screen with many fields.so that i am using **scrolling view** in my layout.But i want to draw **OK** button always.but i am unable to lock the some part of the screen.

i need secreen as:[image: Locked some part for **OK** Button]

but i am getting picture as either [image]

or [image]

i am adding my layout code below(as shown in last pic) plesae help me .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#2E9AFE" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Present Details"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColorHint="#350924"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Present Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#350924"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPreLoc1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Where are u now?"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPreLoc1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Coming By"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#350924"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mmsComing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="car/auto/other" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Vehicle details"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#350924"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etDriver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Driver name/vehicle no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Expected time to reach by:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#350924"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="75" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mmsOk"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a RelativeLayout like that. Just put all you views in the linearlayout inside the scrollview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But last item in scrollView is overlapping with Button

Comment: Oh yes, add an id to your LinearLayout around the button and add  android:layout_above="@+id/id_of_the_linearlayout" to the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Change scrollview height to 0dp and give weight as 1.

Change button layout gravity to bottom instead of center.

Comment: still not coming properly... Now only OK button is displaying in full screen

Comment: did you set the layout weight as 1 for the scroll view?

Comment: yes      <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#2E9AFE" >